# Swift - Autolayout resize button on bigger screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

i'm trying to develop a calculator using swift (see image)

[image: iphone 5s]

since i have not entered any constraints, when i run the app on iphone screen larger than 4 inches, buttons remain in the same position (see image)

[image: iphone 6]

which constraints can i enter to ensure that the size of the buttons can grow with the increase of the screen size? Note that the red view is a content view inside a scroll view so with the following hierarchy:

- View Controller

  - Scroll View

    - Content Red View

      - Buttons

where scroll view has the following constraints: (leading, trailing, bottom and top to his superview) while the content view has: (leading, trailing, bottom, top, equal width and equal height to scroll view)

**EDIT:** *in response to Rizwan Shaikh*
[image: edit]

it works, the only problem is that the container view (red) has become lower than the scroll view (green) when i run the app with iphone 6/6 plus (see image), rather on the iPad the buttons exceeds the size of the container view forcing the scroll view to scroll vertically, why this happening?

**EDIT 2:** *in response to Rizwan Shaikh*

[image: iphone4s]
[image: iphone6]
[image: ipad]

Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why you are taking scroll view?

Comment: pagination, when user scroll horizontally, the scientific calculator is presented

Answer (score 2):

you should used constraint like

```
firstButton LeadingSpace = 20 from mainView    
secondButton LeadingSpace = 20 from firstButton   
thirdButton LeadingSpace = 20 from secondButton  
thirdButton TrailingSpace = 20 from mainView
```

also select all the button in the given row go to Editor -> Pin -> widths  equality
it will make your all  button of same widths
     similarly specify the top and bottomSpace like this

```
firstButton TopSpace = 20 from mainView
fourthButton topSpace = 20 from firstButton // consider 3 button in one row
fourthButton BottomSpace = 20 from MainView
```

Comment: setting just leading and trailing space and also width/height, when i run the app the buttons disappear from the screen

Comment: sorry for late , i see it will work fine . The edit answer is wright it will give constraint on topSpace of each button as in your diagram the firstButton is AC which is give constraint like firstButton TopSpace = 20 from mainView
and fourthButton is like 7 number button so its topSpace = 20 from AC button

Comment: no problem for late, the constraints for all the buttons works fine but force the height of the red view to become smaller then the height of the green view on the iPhone 6/6 plus, otherwise on the iPad buttons exceed the height of the red view making possible to scroll vertically and i don't want that this happening

Comment: make contentView constraint like top.bottom,leading,trailingSpace = 0 from scrollView

Comment: it will show this behaviour only on 6/6 plus? test using 4s,5c

Comment: on viewDidload()  set self.contentRedView.frame.size.width = scrollview.frame.size.width    similarly for height    also refre this answer     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438830/how-to-set-scrollview-content-size-with-auto-layout

Comment: if u have iphone and ipad run the application on your own device and check the behaviour.

Comment: run on iphone and ipad, same problem