# How to adjust Scrollview content size using autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift

Hi in my project i have added scrollview on viewcontroller and inside that scrollview i have added textfields and buttons

After that i have added auto-layouts for all fields as like below image there i have added bottom space container is "58"

but when i clicked on textfield i have changed scrollview content size like below and fine that's ok

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{
   [self.mainscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 700)];

}
```

here my main intention is when i clicked keyboard return button i want to set scroll view content size as like previous what i have applied

for this i have written some code but this showing exceptions please help me

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomSpaceContraint;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.mainscrollview setContentSize:(100, bottomContraint.size.height)];
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set scrollview content size with auto layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438830/how-to-set-scrollview-content-size-with-auto-layout)

Comment: that's not solution for my question

Comment: what is the exceptions you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but if you want to adjust the scroll view based on the presence of the keyboard use the awesome framework [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/). Also, you have tagged your question with swift, but the code you provided is objc. You might wanna change the tag.