# How to change scrollView content sizes using auto-layouts in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am adding 3 UITextfields and 1 UIButton on my scrollview.

My main requirement is when I click on UITextfield scroll must scroll up-to all fields visible to user above keyboard.

And when I click return button on keyboard scroll must scroll by default what in set for scrollview contentSize using auto-layouts.

### my code:

```
@interface ViewController10 ()
{
    UIScrollView * scrollView;
    UITextField * emailTextField;
    UITextField * nameTextField;
    UITextField * passwword;
    UIButton * submit;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController10

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    emailTextField = [self createLabelWithText];
    emailTextField.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview: emailTextField];

    nameTextField = [self createLabelWithText];
    nameTextField.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview: nameTextField];

    passwword = [self createLabelWithText];
    passwword.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview: passwword];

    submit = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    submit.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [submit setTitle: @"Submit" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    submit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:submit];

    NSDictionary * viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,emailTextField,nameTextField,passwword,submit);

    //Applying autolayouts for scrolview

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDic]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDic]];


    //Applying autolayouts for textfields and button

    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:emailTextField
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:0]];

    NSArray * keys = @[@"emailTextField",@"nameTextField",@"passwword",@"submit"];

    for (NSString * key in keys) {

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[%@]-10-|",key]
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDic]];
    }

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-30-[emailTextField(30)]-130-[nameTextField(30)]-130-[passwword(30)]-60-[submit(30)]-20-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:viewsDic]];

}

-(UITextField *)createLabelWithText{

    UITextField * textfield = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textfield.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return textfield;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set scrollview content size with auto layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438830/how-to-set-scrollview-content-size-with-auto-layout)

Comment: my question is completly diff i.e when i click textfileds  scroll must be scroll  up to some contnt size and when i clcik return button in keyboard scroll coming to it's previouse position

Answer (score 0):

Please check this awsome tutorial , it is definetly helpfull for you.

**

> [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

**

as said in blog you need to set constrain in this way when you are using autolayout.

> ```
> NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
>                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
>                                                                   relatedBy:0
>                                                                      toItem:self.view
>                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
>                                                                  multiplier:1.0
>                                                                    constant:0];
> [self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];
>
> NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
>                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
>                                                                    relatedBy:0
>                                                                       toItem:self.view
>                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
>                                                                   multiplier:1.0
>                                                                     constant:0];
> [self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
> ```

change value and name according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When keyBoards is appears .

```
   CGRect frame = currentActiveView.frame; // your scrollview frame 
frame.size.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 216 - keyboardAccesssory.frame.size.height;
currentActiveView.frame = frame;

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
```

When keyboard is resign ..

```
CGRect frame = currentActiveView.frame; // your scrollview frame 
frame.size.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

currentActiveView.frame = frame;

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the frame of the view.
Move the frame above keyboard when keyboard is shown whereas reset its position when keyboard is hidden.
You need to do it programmatically.
You can also go through Apple's Programming guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3